# validRequestorForSendType not called

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an application that adds a menu item to Finder's context menu.

Currently my menu item shows up for any selected item.

I want to perform some filtering and not display my menu item for certain paths.

I believe I've followed the instructions in Apple's Services Implementation Guide[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1) but I have not had any luck accomplishing this.

My understanding is that my filtering logic should be performed in my responder's `validRequestorForSendType` method.  My problem is that this method never gets called, so I am assuming it is not registered in the responder chain but I cannot figure out what I am missing.

I am new to OSX and I inherited this code so here is some additional context which might provide some clues:

The application's sole UI presence is as a tray icon in system menu bar.  Nothing derives from NSApplication (which as I understand it is an NSResponder).  There is a class called AppDelegate which derives from `NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>` where the service provider is set up. In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` this class:

- allocates a MyResponder (derived from NSResponder) instance
- NSRegisterServicesProvider(myResponder, @"*portName from my Info.plist*")
- [NSApp setServicesProvider:myResponder]
- NSUpdateDynamicServices()

In MyResponder's `initialize()` function it calls `[NSApp registerServicesMenuSendTypes]` and defines `validRequestorForSendType` and my service function as listed in the Info.plist.

As previously stated, I run my application, open Finder, click a path and get my application's menu item but never get the opportunity to filter it as MyResponder's `validRequestorForSendType` is not invoked.

Any ideas on what I am missing?  Did I need to wire something up in XCode's xib viewer that I skipped?

Comment: After taking another look at the "Validating Services Menu Items" section of the _Services Implementation Guide_ I'm wondering if validRequestorForSendType is actually a callback for the consumer of the service, not the service itself?
This would align with some other behavior I saw which is that the service menu item displays even if my application is not running. If the user selects it, my application is launched.